# Масив с привязкой к частоте звука

Tags: javascript, css, визуализация

Необходим масив который будет привязан к частоте звука и реагировать в реальном времени, на подобии визуализаторов музыки, в масив хочу привязать кадры анимации (png).
То есть в крации анимация должна меняться в зависимости от звука (например микрофон)

Comment: Без 150 грамм трудно понять, с какой частотой должна меняться анимация, в одном ритме с музыкой? Может заинтересует канвас-визуализация, то подкину ссылку.

Comment: Идея в привязке кадров анимации к показателю частоте, по задумке есть условно 100 кадров анимации и каждый кадр необходимо привязать к определённой частоте, по сути классический визуализатор звука, коих много, однако вместо, классических извивающихся линий, смена png изображений.

Comment: Т. е., в визуализаторе (типа анализатор спектра) 100 частотных полос, и каждую из них должен изображать соответствующий кадр , который будет менять высоту в зависимости от уровня этой частоты? Если не так, то опишите подробно.

Comment: Да в принципе всё так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего количество полос должно являться целой степенью часла 2. В Вашем случа

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Визуализатор</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
img{
    position: absolute; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;
    height: 128px;
    width: 6px;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
</head
<body>
<button onclick="myanalyser()"> старт </button><button onclick="audio.pause()"> стоп </button>
</body>
<script>
var num = 128, // количество частотных полос
steep = 8, // шаг между полосами в пикселях
audio = new Audio("sound.mp3"); // ваш аудиофайл
for(i = 0; i < num; i ++){
    var kadr = document.createElement("img");
    kadr.id = "k" + i;
    kadr.src = "kadr" + i + ".png";
    kadr.style.left = i * steep + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(kadr);
}
function myanalyser(){
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext(),
    source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio),
    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = num * 2;
    source.connect(analyser); // Подключаем анализатор к элементу audio
    analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination); // Без этой строки нет звука, но анализатор работает.
    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    setInterval(function(){
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData); // Записываем в массив данные уровней частот
        for(i = 0; i < num; i ++) document.getElementById("k" + i).style.height = frequencyData[i] + "px";
    }, 20);
    audio.play();
}
// myanalyser(); // если нужно автовоспроизведение в хроме
</script>
</html>
```

е подойдёт 128.

Comment: Аудио работает только при audio.onplay () без () не срабатывает, но не суть. Я подставил своё аудио, и создал изображения с соответствующими названиями, скрипт создаёт изображения однако src у них указан как <img id="k1" src="k" style="left: 16px;"> <img id="k2" src="a" style="left: 16px;"> <img id="k3" src="d" style="left: 16px;"> <img id="k4" src="r" style="left: 16px;">, то есть он слово кадр разбивает а последующие помечены как "undefined".

Comment: Строку kadrsArray = ("kadr0.jpg", "kadr1.jpg", "kadr2.jpg", "kadr127.jpg"); я не менял специально, просто создал соответствующие изображения

Comment: Странно, ведёт себя так, буд-то 12 строка напмсана так: ** kadr..src = "kadr"[i];**

Comment: Я нашёл ошибку. Массив должен быть объявлен в квадратных скобках, а не в круглых Т. е., kadrsArray = ["kadr0.jpg", "kadr1.jpg", "kadr2.jpg", "kadr127.jpg"];  В ответе исправил.

Comment: А вот audio.onplay ()  со скобками у меня наоборот выдаёт **Uncaught TypeError: audio.onplay is not a function**

Comment: Как-то так и не получилось у меня вывести. И я искал есть ли способ 128 кадров мне в массив прописать более лёгким способом чем просто прописывать каждый отдельно.

Comment: Разумеется способ есть. Сейчас  переделаю ответ

Comment: Исправил. Теперь массив и id кадров не нужны вообще.

Comment: всё таки id нужен.

Comment: Долго не мог понять проблему с выводом фото, потом нашёл опечатку "audio = new Audio("sound.mp3")," и почему-то аудио не включается вместе с функцией анализа

Comment: Удалял функцию audio.onplay = function(){  и аудио работает а с ней нет

Comment: При чём сутя по изменениям анализ и изменения после анализа применяются просто нет аудио которое бы работало. При чём изменения работают вплоть до 63-го кадра.

Comment: В конце 20 строки запятую замените на точку с запятой, я был ошибся

Comment: Запятую я заменил и аудио работает, но только без анализатора, с анализатором оно не включается.

Comment: Я изменил ответ, теперь функция  **audio.onplay()** не используется и обрабатываются 128 кадров. Попробуйте. На всякий случай живая ссылка: [анализатор](http://opan.strana.de/myradio/analiser.html) только без изображений.

Comment: Получилось запустить, анализатор работает, Спасибо!
Теперь думаю как сделать, то же самое только чтоб анализатор ориентировался на громкость звука.

Comment: Первый способ: после 15 строки вставляем это: **<input type=range onchange="audio.volume=this.value/100" />
** Второй способ: после 20 сроки вставляем это:  **audio.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(audio);** Появится стандартная панель аудио, и там регулятор громкости, приаязанный к анализатору.

Comment: Первый способ лучше сделать так:
**<input type=range onmousemove="audio.volume=Math.pow(1.00695, this.value) - 1" />**
Тогда будет более глубокая регулировка громкости так как она будет меняться по логарифмической шкале. При этом с каждым одинаковым шагом ползунка она меняется на одинаковое количество децибел.